# When I push a button in my app, all of the editText and TextViews move to the left side of the Screen

Tags: java, android, android-textinputedittext

I am trying to build an app in android studios for a class and I am trying to test my app on an Samsung Galaxy S4. when I push a button on the screen to save the data the user inputs, all of the editText and TextViews get shifted to the left side of the screen and i do not know why it does this. 
Here is my code for the XML:

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/display_data"
    android:id="@+id/DisplayData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="DisplayData"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/GoalPercent"
    android:text="@string/competition_percentage"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textGoal"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textGoal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textGoal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GoalPercent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GoalPercent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Temp"
    android:id="@+id/textTemp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GoalPercent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GoalPercent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textGoal"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textGoal" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/current_heart_rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/HR"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Temp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Temp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Temp" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/body_temperature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Temp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/GoalPercent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GoalPercent"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/GoalPercent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textHR"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/HR"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/HR"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textTemp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textTemp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinGender"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:entries="@array/gender_choice"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Gender"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Gender"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/enterFeet"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/enterFeet" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/gender_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Gender"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Steps"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Steps" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/enterStep"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:hint="@string/enter_value"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SetStep"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textSteps"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textSteps"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
    android:maxHeight="35dip"
    android:minHeight="35dip"
    android:scrollbarSize="200dp"
    android:maxWidth="10dip"
    android:minWidth="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SetStep"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/total_steps_today"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Steps"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    tools:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enterLbs"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textSteps"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"

    android:layout_below="@+id/enterLbs"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GoalPercent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GoalPercent" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/set_step_goal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SetStep"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:onClick="SetGoal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Steps"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/lbs"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:ems="5"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/enterLbs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enterFeet"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textSteps"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textSteps"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/enterFeet"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/enterFeet" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/enter_your_height"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinGender"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Gender"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Gender"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/enter_your_weight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Weight"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enterLbs"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enterLbs"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Height"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Height" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/feet"
    android:ems="4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/enterFeet"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinGender"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textSteps"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textSteps" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/enterInches"
    android:hint="@string/inches"
    android:ems="4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinGender"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my Function for when the button is pushed:

```
public void SetGoal(View v) {

    Max = Integer.parseInt(Goal.getText().toString());
    GoalProgressBar.setMax(Max);
    GoalProgressBar.setProgress(Steps);
    //display goal completion percentage
    goalpercent = (Steps / Max) * 100;
    GoalPer.setText(Integer.toString(goalpercent));
}
```

I can not use an emulator on my computer. For some reason my computer won't run any of the emulators in the AVD Managers. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your editText and TextViews depends on GoalPercent (ProgressBar) alignment in layout. That why editText and TextViews changed the position in layout when GoalPercent (ProgressBar) display or hidden.

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GoalPercent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GoalPercent"
```

Remove it and redesign widget not depends on GoalPercent ProgressBar.